# Jobs allocate twice the cores that I request on SLURM

Tags: memory-management, cpu-usage, hpc, slurm, snakemake

I am trying to understand why twice the amount of cores I request are being allocated to my sbatch jobs.
From what I can tell, my partition has 106 threads:

```
    [.... snake_make]$ sinfo -p mypartition -o %z
S:C:T
2:26:2
```

Yet with the sbatch set like so for my snakemake:

> module load snakemake/5.6.0
> snakemake -s snake_make_tetragonula --cluster-config cluster.yaml --jobs 70 
> --cluster "sbatch -n 4 -M {cluster.cluster} -A {cluster.account} -p {cluster.partition}" 
> --latency-wait 10

Each job is being allocated 8 cores instead of 4. When I run squeue, I see that it is only able to run as many as 12 jobs at a time, suggesting that it is using 8 cores for each job despite me specifying 4 threads. Also when I look at my job usage on XDMoD, I see that only half of the cpus on the job are getting used. How can I use exactly as many cpus as I want and not double that amount, like it is currently running? I have also tried

> --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=4

which still doubled it to 8. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slurm can only allocate cores, not threads. So, with such a configuration:

```
S:C:T
2:26:2
```

two threads are allocated to jobs for each core being requested. Two hardware threads cannot be allocated to distinct jobs.

You can try with

```
--ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=2 --threads-per-core=2
```

But, if your computation is CPU-intensive, this can make your jobs slower.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have cpus per task set to half the number of threads I am calling for my snakemake rule and now my core number equals the number of threads allocated, rather than double. I will keep an eye on those jobs to see if they are markedly slower.

Comment: Wow, this information was impossible to find in the documentation. You would think this would be kind of important for users. Where did you acquire this information, if I may ask?

Comment: In https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html: "On nodes with hyper-threads, each thread is counted as a CPU to satisfy a job's resource requirement, but multiple jobs are not allocated threads on the same core."